# Pycharm console output not fully display as stored in variable

Tags: pycharm

New to Pycharm here. I am trying to get the full output from my code but somehow it is shorten or converted in the console. Below are my code:

```
import subprocess
import os

wdir='D:\Microvirt\MEmu'
os.chdir(wdir)
process = subprocess.Popen("adb shell screencap -p", shell=True, 
stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
screenshot = process.stdout.read()
print(screenshot)
```

Pycharm Console Image:
[image]

Why is it differrent in the console output and the content stored in the variable ? How can I made it to display the same as in the variable on the right hand side ? Thank you for taking time to read.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by printing binary data to the console?

Comment: I am actually following some tutorial and their result of binary data on the console is different than mine. So I was wondering what is the changes i have to make to have the full display on console, so that I can have easier time understand the tutorial.

Comment: Binary data is not supposed to be displayed in the console, so there is absolutely no guarantee what results you're going to get. To get predictable results, convert your data to text (for example, if you want to compare the byte values, you can convert the data to hexadecimal numbers).

Comment: Yup it's working now ! Thanks you !!